# Normal distribution for bags of coal produced from a machine.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

A machine is used to bag coal, the mass of coal delivered per bag being normally distributed with mean 55 Kg and standard deviation 1.25 Kg.

Given two filled bags chosen at random calculate the probabilities that

(i) each bag contains at least 56 Kg
(ii) one bag contains at least 1 Kg more than the other bag

Answers: (i) 0.045 and (ii) 0.572

For (i) the combined mean of the 2 bags is 112 Kg and the standard deviation is 1.25 + 1.25 = 2.50

For (ii) Let one bag be X and the other Y so we have mod(X-Y)>1. The mean is E(X) - E(Y) = 0  and we have Var(X) + Var(Y) = 3.125, so we have a standard deviation of sqrt(3.125).

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**

For (i), you have both $X,Y \sim \mathcal{N}(55, 1.25)$ and $X,Y$ are independent.

Then,
$$
\mathbb{P}[X > 56, Y > 56]
   = \mathbb{P}[X > 56] \times \mathbb{P}[Y > 56]
$$
but $X,Y$ have the same distribution, can you take it from here?

For (ii), look at $\mathbb{P}[|X-Y| > 1]$ using the joint distribution between $X$ and $Y$, or condition on $Y$. Note that $|X-Y| > 1$ means either $X-Y>1$ or $Y-X>1$...

Comment: (i) We have 2 bags so mean = 56 + 56 = 112 and the standard deviation is 1.25 + 1.25 = 2.5 for both X and Y with the same distribution or using a joint distribution. Now                               P(z > (112 - 110) / 2.5 ) = P(z > 0.8) = 0.2119 ( from the z- table). From your hint that we need to multiply the probabilities together we get (0.2119)^2 = 0.045. Thanks.

Comment: @Julian you just copied over your claim from the original question, it will not fit for the solution method i am proposing. What is $\mathbb{P}[X > 56] \times \mathbb{P}[Y > 56]$??

Comment: 0.2119 x 0.2119 = 0.045 (calculation above). We could just have done P(z> 56-55/1.25) = P(z>0.8) = 0.2119 for either X or Y. Then square this result to get the answer as they both have the same distribution.

Comment: @Julian notice this matches the answer given in (i). Can you take care of (ii)?

Comment: Let X be the weight of one bag and Y be the weight of the other bag.

Modulus(X-Y)>1 so we have a mean of 0 and a variance of sqrt(3.125).

P(z > (1-0)/sqrt(3.125)) = 1 - P(z< (1-0)/sqrt(3.125)) = 1 - P(z< 0.5657)

From the z-tables we have P(z< 0.5657) = 0.7142 so 1-0.7142 = 0.2858.

This represents the tail end of the normal distribution curve on the positive side and by symmetry the other end is the same so we have 2 * 0.2858 = 0.5716, which gives 0.572 to 3dp.

Comment: @J132 same error here as in your other question -- if $Z = |X-Y|$ then $Z \ge 0$ so $\mathbb{E}[Z] \ge 0$...

Comment: For both of the bags that were selected we have assumed that the mean for both is 55Kg, in our method. So the difference between them is 0. (We can have X > Y or Y > X, which is why we are looking at |X - Y|).

Comment: @J132 no this is incorrect, see my comment to your other question